# group the query to find the data by grouping the txn month in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, aggregate-functions

I have the below 2 queries which I am using the find new and returning customers. For finding the new and ret customer for each month I have to run the below query by changing the dates. For example if I am running the query for the month of Jan, Feb March I have to run it 3 times. Is there a way to just run it once to get the 3 months of data ? I tried to join it to our fiscal calendar table and grouped it by fiscal month but it gives me a different number for each month compares to when I run it seperately.

**This is my original query which I am running multiple times.**

```
SELECT
    DECODE(is_new, 1, 'New Customers', 'Returning Customers') type_of_customer,
    COUNT(distinct individual_id) count_of_customers,
    sum(dollar_value_us) dollar_value_us,
    sum(Margin),
    SUM(count_of_transactions) count_of_transactions,
    SUM(sum_of_quantity) sum_of_quantity
    from (
SELECT DISTINCT
             individual_id,
             SUM (dollar_value_us)             dollar_value_us,
             SUM (quantity)                    sum_of_quantity,
             sum(dollar_value_us) - sum(cogs*quantity) as Margin,
             COUNT (DISTINCT transaction_number) count_of_transactions,
             CASE WHEN MIN (TRUNC (txn_date)) = min_txn_date THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                 is_new
        FROM (SELECT individual_id,
                     dollar_value_us,
                     txn_date,
                     quantity,
                     cogs,
                     transaction_number,
                     MIN (TRUNC (txn_date)) OVER (PARTITION BY individual_id)
                         min_txn_date
               FROM TRANSACTION_table A JOIN sku_table B ON A.SKU = B.ITEM
               WHERE     brand_org_code = 'brand'
                      and "sku" = 'SKU1')
       WHERE TRUNC (txn_date) BETWEEN '01-JAN-20' AND '31-JAN-20'
       and INDIVIDUAL_ID is not null
    GROUP BY individual_id, min_txn_date)
    group by is_new;
```

**This is the query which I combined with the fiscal calendar table to group it by fiscal month so that I do not have to run the query again and again for each month, but the data which comes back does not match with the data when I run the above query individually.**

```
SELECT
    DECODE(is_new, 1, 'New Customers', 'Returning Customers') type_of_customer,
    FISCAL_YEAR_MONTH,
    COUNT(distinct individual_id) count_of_customers,
    sum(dollar_value_us) dollar_value_us,
    sum(Margin),
    SUM(count_of_transactions) count_of_transactions,
    SUM(sum_of_quantity) sum_of_quantity
    from (
SELECT DISTINCT
             individual_id,
             FISCAL_YEAR_MONTH,
             SUM (dollar_value_us)             dollar_value_us,
             SUM (quantity)                    sum_of_quantity,
             sum(dollar_value_us) - sum(cogs*quantity) as Margin,
             COUNT (DISTINCT transaction_number) count_of_transactions,
             CASE WHEN MIN (TRUNC (txn_date)) = min_txn_date THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                 is_new
        FROM (SELECT individual_id,
                     dollar_value_us,
                     txn_date,
                     FISCAL_YEAR_MONTH,
                     quantity,
                     cogs,
                     transaction_number,
                     MIN (TRUNC (txn_date)) OVER (PARTITION BY individual_id)
                         min_txn_date
               FROM TRANSACTION_table A JOIN sku_table B ON A.SKU = B.ITEM
               WHERE brand_org_code = 'brand'
               and "sku" = 'SKU1') A join fiscal_calendar_table c on a.TRUNC(A.TXN_DATE) = C.DATE_ID
       WHERE TRUNC (txn_date) BETWEEN '01-JAN-20' AND '31-JAN-20'
       and INDIVIDUAL_ID is not null
    GROUP BY individual_id, min_txn_date, FISCAL_YEAR_MONTH)
    group by is_new, FISCAL_YEAR_MONTH;
```

Any kind of help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Do your fiscal months align to 1st and last day of calendar months? I suggest you read these: [Provide a `Minimal Complete Verifiable Example` (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
and [Why should I provide a MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: if you filter the second query by a date range `'01-JAN-20' AND '31-JAN-20'` then you get no benefit from the extra join and there's not much point in grouping by fiscal month

Comment: @PaulMaxwell yes that was a mistake, the date range in the second query should be '01-JAN-20' AND '31-MAR-20'